# bluetooth headphones disconnect and reconnect every 30 mins on ubuntu 22.04 when upgraded from 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, bluez, blueman

My Bluetooth headphones keep disconnecting and reconnecting every 20-30 minutes. It has been quite annoying, I've tried to search for solutions, but sadly none of them seems to work, I'm new to Linux and followed a Reddit thread which said downgrading the Bluetooth firmware might fix the issue, but that didn't work :\

These are the logs I get with `journalctl -f | grep -i blue` when the headphones disconnect and reconnect.

```
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluetoothd[25853]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:handle_unanswered_req() No reply to Suspend request
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook wireplumber[2984]: Failed to release transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_85_3B_B9/sep1/fd8: Input/output error
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1009: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesRemoved()
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook dbus-daemon[1251]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.41" (uid=1000 pid=2984 comm="/usr/bin/wireplumber " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.103" (uid=0 pid=25853 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluetoothd[25853]: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Aug 13 23:02:43 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1009: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesRemoved()
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:915: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded()
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:998: Adding new Stream End-Point: 18:95:52:85:3B:B9: SBC
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:915: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded()
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1068: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged()
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: E: Device not available: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_85_3B_B9/fd9
Aug 13 23:02:44 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluetoothd[25853]: plugins/policy.c:reconnect_timeout() Reconnecting services failed: Operation already in progress (114)
Aug 13 23:02:52 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook dbus-daemon[1251]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.41" (uid=1000 pid=2984 comm="/usr/bin/wireplumber " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.103" (uid=0 pid=25853 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Aug 13 23:02:52 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1009: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesRemoved()
Aug 13 23:02:52 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:915: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded()
Aug 13 23:02:54 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1068: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged()
Aug 13 23:02:54 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: E: Device not available: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_85_3B_B9/sep1/fd10
Aug 13 23:03:09 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook dbus-daemon[1251]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.41" (uid=1000 pid=2984 comm="/usr/bin/wireplumber " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.103" (uid=0 pid=25853 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Aug 13 23:03:09 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1009: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesRemoved()
Aug 13 23:03:10 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:915: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.InterfacesAdded()
Aug 13 23:03:11 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: D: bluez.c:1068: Signal: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged()
Aug 13 23:03:11 aditya-HP-Pavillion-Notebook bluealsa[25855]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: E: Device not available: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_18_95_52_85_3B_B9/sep1/fd11
```